# UserSearchFilter&managerDn issue when authenticating to LDAP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

I’m trying to connect the LDAP using the following code:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>


auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .managerDn("CN=someValidLogin,OU=UsersGeneric,OU=IT,OU=Penzberg,OU=AdminUnits,DC=emea,DC=rr,DC=com")
            .managerPassword("someValidPassword")
            .url("ldap://abc.def.ghi.com:3268/DC=emea,DC=rr,DC=com")
            .and()
            .userSearchFilter("(&(sAMAccountName={0})(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(memberOf=CN=TEST_DEVELOPER,OU=Applications,OU=Groups,DC=emea,DC=rr,DC=com))")
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordAttribute("userpassword");
```

Unfortunately, after typing my correct credentials in the swagger I’m getting the response:

```
[LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C091146, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839]; nested exception is javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C091146, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839]; remaining name ‘CN=loginThatIPassedViaSwagger,OU=Users,OU=IT,OU=Warsaw,OU=AdminUnits’
```

Likely, I mixed something with managerDn and userSearchFilter, but I cannot figure out what?

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I have figured out that the following works:

```
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .groupSearchBase("")
        .contextSource()
        .managerDn("CN=someValidLogin,OU=UsersGeneric,OU=IT,OU=Penzberg,OU=AdminUnits,DC=emea,DC=rr,DC=com")
        .managerPassword("someValidPassword")
        .url("ldap://abc.def.ghi.com:3268")
        .and()
        .userSearchBase("")
        .userSearchFilter(
                "(&(sAMAccountName={0})(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(|(memberOf:1.2.333.12345.1.4.1941:=CN=TEST_DEVELOPER,OU=Applications,OU=Groups,DC=emea,DC=rr,DC=com)))");
```